# how to use JdbcTemplate in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-batch

I'm trying to use Spring JdbcTemplate with Spring's SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor so that concurrent connections to the DB 
can be made and the whole data can be inserted into the related table in a smaller amount of time when compared to a single threaded environment.

I'm using the following code, however it doesn't speed up my application.

The only clue I could find is the fact that the bean "campaignProductDBWriter" is constructed only once whereas I'm expecting 10 seperate instances to be created
as I set "throttle-limit" to 10 in the tasklet.

What am I doing wrong? Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

```
<bean id="dataSourceProduct"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
  p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url.product}"
  p:username="${jdbc.username.product}" p:password="${jdbc.password.product}" 
/>

<bean id="jdbcTemplateProduct" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceProduct" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" >
  <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="-1" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="sampleJob" restartable="true"  incrementer="dynamicJobParameters">             
  <batch:step id="mapMZList">
    <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true" task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="10">                     
      <batch:chunk reader="campaignProductItemReader" processor="campaignProductProcessor" writer="campaignProductDBWriter" commit-interval="5000"/>        
    </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>                 
</batch:job>

<bean id="campaignProductDBWriter" class="com.falcon.cc.job.step.CampaignProductWriter">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplateProduct" />
</bean>


<bean id="campaignProductItemReader" class="com.falcon.cc.job.step.FlatFileSynchronizedItemReader" scope="step">    
  <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['input.TEST_FILE.path']}"/>

  <property name="lineMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">        
      <property name="lineTokenizer">       
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
          <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>            
          <property name="names" value="approvalStatus,validFrom,validTo"/>
        </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="fieldSetMapper">
        <bean class="com.falcon.cc.mapper.CampaignProductFieldSetMapper" />
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Just a generic observation, many JDBC drivers are NOT threadsafe, so for 10 threads to be running safely you'd need 10 connections. Have you tried using BatchUpdate? Though I've heard of difficulties there as well.

Comment: @skaffman "There is no variation" That isn't true, even in the spec, from the spec "For example, two Statements on the same Connection can be executed concurrently and their ResultSets can be processed concurrently (from the perspective of the developer). Some drivers will provide this full concurrency. Others may execute one statement and wait until it completes before sending the next." I know that thread safety was a new feature in the Oracle OCI for 9i. So I guess you're right in that they should be thread safe...but not all are guaranteed to be useful concurrently.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a problem with your Spring config, or with how you're using `jdbcTemplate`, which is just a thin, stateless wrapper around the JDBC API.

The most obvious likelihood is that your bottleneck is your database, not your code. It's entirely possible that running multiple concurrent operations against the database is no faster than doing them one at a time.

There could be several reasons for this, such as database locking, or just lack of raw I/O performance.

When considering using multi-threading to improve performance, you have to be sure where your bottlenecks are. If your code isn't the bottleneck, then making it multi-threaded isn't going to make things any faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still curious about why the bean campaignProductDBWriter is constructed only once whereas I'm expecting 10 different instances to be constructed. I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

When spring's context is initialized, it creates all instances declared in the context. 
`<bean id="campaignProductDBWriter" class="com.falcon.cc.job.step.CampaignProductWriter">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplateProduct" />
</bean>` this code will result in spring creating an instance of `CampaignProductWriter` which will be a singleton (as by default the scope is singleton).
In order to have a new instance of your bean, its scope have to be prototype.